# Strange Errors in Python-Mode

Tags: indentation, python

I am using the python mode. When i try to evaluate the following `def` using `C-M-x` i get this error from the python interpreter which looks strange:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    print args, kwargs

>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/amir/programming/python/tst.py", line 2
    if True:
           ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Can any one say why this happens? The file is only including the above function definition beginning from the first line an nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like code was sent to a Python3 shell, where `print` is a function.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `py-execute-def-python2` <kbd>RET</kbd> should work.

Customizing `py-shell-name` is an option too.